# Accessing variables using overloading brackets [] in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, overriding, overloading

Hi i want to do the following. I simply want to overload the [] method in order to access the instance variables... I know, it doesn't make great sense at all, but i want to do this for some strange reason :P

It will be something like this...

```
class Wata

    attr_accessor :nombre, :edad

    def initialize(n,e)
        @nombre = n
        @edad   = e
    end

    def [](iv)
        self.iv
    end

end

juan = Wata.new('juan',123)

puts juan['nombre']
```

But this throw the following error:

overload.rb:11:in `[]': undefined method 'iv' for # (NoMethodError)

How can i do that?

**EDIT**

I have found also this solution:

```
def [](iv)
    eval("self."+iv)
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables and messages live in a different namespace. In order to send the variable as a message, you'd need to define it as either:

```
def [](iv)
    send iv
end
```

(if you want to get it through an accessor)

or

```
def [](iv)
    instance_variable_get "@#{iv}"
end
```

(if you want to access the ivar directly)

Comment: Excellent Chuck! I didn't know anything about sending a variable...
It also works with instance_variable_get

Thanks..

Comment: send works with methods only, attr_accessor adds both setter and getter methods for you, so send basically is calling the getter.

Answer (score 4):

try [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.src/M000367.html) instead:

```
 def [](iv)
     instance_variable_get("@#{iv}")
 end
```