# Can we write a hash without hash class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associative-array

For the sake of this question lets assume that we don't have a `hash` class in Ruby.

Is it possible to create a `hash` without using `hash class` in Ruby? Or probably if we don't have a hash concept, we may be calling it `associative array`.

Comment: You wouldn't get the nice Ruby literal syntax, but Ruby *does* allow operator overloading. You could define a class that overloads the bracket operator and implements a hash table the usual way. This might have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903183/accessing-variables-using-overloading-brackets-in-ruby)

Comment: [This page](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/hash-lookup-in-ruby-why-is-it-so-fast) also explains how to create a hash table in Ruby.

Comment: It's possible but there'd be a drastic difference in average speed of lookups. Hashes outrun Arrays when used for lookups.

Comment: @theTinMan: Rubinius's `Hash` is pure Ruby and performs competitive with YARV's, which is written in hand-optimized C. Which shows that, at least in some circumstances, Rubinius's native code compiler can generate code as well as GCC -O2. (If I were PR person, I would phrase that as "Ruby is as fast as C." But I am not.)

Comment: "Ruby is as fast as C" :-) That'd cause an uproar!

Comment: @theTinMan: That sentence has no meaning. Statistically, if you want to figure out whether the change of language has an impact on the performance, you need to isolate your variables, i.e. you must only change the language and nothing else. However, that's not possible: you have to *at least* change the benchmark (because you need to re-write it in a different language) and the compiler (because it doesn't understand the other language). But now you haven't just tested two languages against each other, you have tested two different benchmarks written in two different languages compiled by …

Comment: … two different compilers against each other. IOW: you have changed three variables, not one, and you cannot (generally) tell which of the three variables had how much impact in which direction on the result. IOW: when people say "C is faster than Ruby", what they are *really* saying is "this particular benchmark written in C, compiled by GCC in this particular benchmark run runs faster than this totally different benchmark written in Ruby, compiled by a totally different compiler." Well, I provided an example where the opposite is (nearly) true, so by the same logic I get to make the opposite

Comment: … claim, do I not? ;-) (Honestly, it's not really that hard. Just run the C benchmarks with Cint, which is, I believe, about 10000–100000 times slower than GCC, which makes it about 10–1000 times slower than YARV. Boom! Instant benchmark win for Ruby, "Ruby is faster than C, yay!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to use an Array to simulate the behavior of a Hash, performance is going to suffer:

```
require 'fruity'

CHARS = ('a' .. 'z').to_a
ARY = CHARS.zip(CHARS)
HASH = ARY.to_h

compare do 
  _assoc_a { ARY.assoc('a') }
  _hash_a  { HASH['a']      }
  _hash_m  { HASH['m']      }
  _assoc_m { ARY.assoc('m') }
  _assoc_z { ARY.assoc('z') }
  _hash_z  { HASH['z']      }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 3 seconds.
# >> _hash_m is similar to _hash_z (results differ: m vs z)
# >> _hash_z is similar to _hash_a (results differ: z vs a)
# >> _hash_a is faster than _assoc_a by 2x ± 1.0 (results differ: a vs ["a", "a"])
# >> _assoc_a is faster than _assoc_m by 5x ± 1.0 (results differ: ["a", "a"] vs ["m", "m"])
# >> _assoc_m is faster than _assoc_z by 2x ± 0.1 (results differ: ["m", "m"] vs ["z", "z"])
```

Doing reverse lookups, from the second element to the first, or from the value to the key:

```
compare do
  _rassoc_a      { ARY.rassoc('a')  }
  _hash_rassoc_a { HASH.rassoc('a') }
  _rassoc_m      { ARY.rassoc('m')  }
  _hash_rassoc_m { HASH.rassoc('m') }
  _rassoc_z      { ARY.rassoc('z')  }
  _hash_rassoc_z { HASH.rassoc('z') }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
# >> _rassoc_a is faster than _hash_rassoc_a by 2x ± 1.0
# >> _hash_rassoc_a is faster than _rassoc_m by 3x ± 1.0 (results differ: ["a", "a"] vs ["m", "m"])
# >> _rassoc_m is similar to _hash_rassoc_m
# >> _hash_rassoc_m is similar to _rassoc_z (results differ: ["m", "m"] vs ["z", "z"])
# >> _rassoc_z is similar to _hash_rassoc_z
```

It makes sense to me that a reverse lookup of the hash to the key would be slower, since a hash isn't optimized for such things. If I need to do that I try to create a separate Hash reversing the keys and values then use that to do reverse lookups:

```
hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
reversed_hash = hash.invert # => {1=>"a", 2=>"b"}
```

This breaks if the value is an array or the values are not unique, and sometimes the resulting key isn't very convenient to use.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a `hash` without using `hash class` in Ruby? Or probably if we don't have a hash concept, we may be calling it `associative array`.

Of course. Why wouldn't it be? The concept of a hash table is not tied to any particular language.

Also, Ruby is a Turing-complete language, which means that you can compute everything in Ruby which you can also compute in any other language.

[Rubinius's `Hash` class](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb) is written in pure Ruby, and it obviously cannot use the `Hash` class, so clearly it is possible to write `Hash` in pure Ruby. And why wouldn't it be? YARV's `Hash` class is written in C, JRuby's `Hash` class is written in Java, IronRuby's in C♯, Topaz's in RPython, and if you want to write one in Ruby, you "just" have to write the same thing as those all did, except in Ruby instead of C, Java, C♯, or RPython.

(To be fair, Rubinius's `Hash` implementation uses [`Tuple`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/tuple.rb), which is [partially implemented in C++](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/builtin/tuple.cpp), but again, you just have to re-write that code in Ruby, et voilà, you have a `Hash` class in Ruby.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of recreating your own hash class you can use the Array class's `assoc` and `rassoc` methods. See "[Associative arrays in Ruby...what?](http://blog.honeybadger.io/associative-arrays-in-ruby-what/)".

Examples:

```
picks = [
 ["AAPL", "buy"],
 ["GOOG", "sell"],
 ["MSFT", "sell"]
]

print picks.assoc("AAPL")
puts #new line 
print picks.rassoc("sell") #gets the first row that contains
```

Output:

```
["AAPL", "buy"]
["GOOG", "sell"]
```

Comment: While you _can_ create something similar using Array, `assoc` and `rassoc` are not close to the lookup speed of using a true hash unless the target is immediately found, since they have to walk the array to find the desired element. When a target is at the end of the array the response time will really drop.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for pointing out the performance hit (and the edits).